# Inclusion-exclusion in dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, math

There are N soldiers (numbered from 1 to N). Each soldier has some subset of skills out of M different skills (numbered from 1 to M). The skill-set of an army is the union of skill-sets of its constituent soldiers. How many different subsets of soldiers satisfy are there which have specific skill-set requirement

[Problem Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w16/challenges/vim-war)

According to the Explanation problem reduces to finding the number of subsets of these numbers whose OR is exactly equal to the required value, say req

Let f(i) be the number of numbers j such that j OR i = i.
Then the answer is
**∑i(−1)^popcount(i xor req)(2^f(i)−1) for all i such that i OR req is req**

Please Explain the above formula and How it came
I know No. of ways to choose N element is (2^n-1) but why this term `(−1)^popcount(i xor req)`

Please Explain the algorithm.

Comment: What exactly is `popcount` supposed to be?

Comment: It counts the number of set bit in a binary representation of a number

Comment: You might want to post the exact wording of the editorial, which also has code. Your `f` definition is not exactly the same as it is there.

Comment: @IVlad could you please  explain me the algorithm that would be a great help for me in learning new thing

Comment: From the form of the formula I'm guessing it may be related to [inclusion exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the editorial and got AC myself, I do not think it is that easy to understand the application of "Inclusion-Exclusion Principle" here, this problem is around Codeforces Div.1 Problem C / D level, for example, this one: http://codeforces.com/contest/449/problem/D

**Rewritten Version@2016**

> Previous answer is too messy, I try to clean it up and rewrite a more readable answer

I am going to explain why the solution works, but **not** *how to come up with such solution*, I think that's more about experience.

**Big Picture Explanation**

First, do not over think the problem, given `a[1..N]`, the solution is literally *all subsets that can produce `req`*

Being said, how can we find all subset that can produce `x`? 
As the solution shows, let's define `f(i)`

> Let `f(i)`be the number of numbers  such that `j` OR `i` = `i`.

If you find it hard to understand, think its physical meaning:

> For any `i`,  `j` OR `i` = `i` **iff** `j` can be produced by *take away some binary bit 1 away from* `i`

For example, if `i` = 7, then `j` can be 0,1,2...,7;  if `i`=5, then `j` can be 0,1,4,5

So, `2^f(i) - 1` is indeed the # of possible subsets which can produce `i` when OR `i`

**Hold a second here, make sure you get over the above part first.**

Now what if `i` = `req` itself?  What does it means? Which subsets are counted in `2^f(req)-1`? How does `2^f(req)-1` related to the answer we want?

> We want the # of subsets which OR all elements will produce `req`
>
> `2^f(req)-1` gives the # of subsets which OR all elements OR `req` will produce `req`

Can you smell that `2^f(req)-1` is likely count more than we need?

Think like this: There are some subsets `2^f(req)-1` counts, which OR all elements can only produce `x` where `x` can be produced by take away some binary bit 1 from `req` (See block Quote above)

So, we have to minus something from `2^f(req)-1`, and here comes **Inclusion-Exclusion Principle**.

Let's say we want to minus those subsets which OR all elements is equal to `x`, which is `req` take away one binary bit 1

With similar thoughts, you will find that you have to minus `2^f(x)-1` , for all possible `x`, here, remember *`x` is all numbers which is `req` take away one binary bit 1*

But then, you are going to minus more than you should, because different `x` may share same `y`, where `y` is `req` take away **two** binary bit 1, or `y` is `x` take away one binary bit 1, you are suppose to remove exactly one time for each `y` from `2^f(req)-1`, but in the process of minus `2^f(x)-1`, you have minus multiple times for some `y`!

By Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, you have to add them back...Let's have a little summary here:

> What we want is `2^f(req)-1`  -  `2^f(x)-1`  + `2^f(y)-1` ... where `x` is set of numbers equal to `req` remove one binary bit 1, `y` is set of numbers equal to `req` remove two binary bit 1 (or `x` remove one binary bit 1)

Can you see the pattern here? Yes, that's the `-1^popcount()` part in the formula

For all `i` <= `req`, **every bit of `i` is either same as `req` or 0**, then `i xor req` is equal to `req - i`(remove all 1-bit of `i`),  **so `popcount(i xor req)` indeed gives the # of binary bit 1 to be removed from `req` in order to get `i`**

Combined whole story, the formula is formed: `Sum (-1)^popcount(i xor req) * (2^f(i) - 1)` for all `i` such that `i OR req = req`

**DP to calculate f(i)**

```js
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)  
    for(int j=0; j<=(1<<20); j++) {  
         if(j&(1<<i)) {  
             f[j] += f[j^(1<<i)];  
         }  
    }
```

Here is the DP part to calculate `f(i)`

Note that it is base on the following recurrence relation:

> f(i) = `i` itself + f(some j which is i remove some bit 1)
>
> So, f(i) = 1 + f(i xor (1 << j)) if i's j-th bit is 1

Note that `i xor (1<<j)` must be smaller than `i`, hence the DP order.

Comment: could you explain the codeforce problem also how Inclusion-Exclusion Principle is used in there  i wonder if F[x]=v and freq. of getting x is 0 but we are still counting in our answer.Please Explain

Comment: Yes I will edit now, but do you understand my explanation for hackerrank's problem beforehand? As they are related

Comment: i am working on  it will let you know please explain that codeforce problem also it will clear my inclusion exclusion principle thanks !!!!

Comment: how `popcount(i)` is used still can't understand it in codeforce question

Comment: f(i) represent number of elements where i&A=i but our aim is calculated set  where and is zero how this is achieve since 2^f(i) will give element where end is i

Comment: Consider f(0), it represents # of elements j such that j & 0 = 0, right?
but what is 2^f(j) ? It's the number of all possible subsets, and obviously not all of them will give a 0 when we AND all of its elements. For example, you may try input 1 and 3 as the only elements, obviously no non-empty subset of {1,3} can produce 0, but f(0) = 2, 2^f(0) = 4 !! And it is why we need Inclusion-Exclusion, we have to minus away some subset which is not the answer, which goes back to my original answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84035/discussion-between-tony-stark007-and-shole).

Answer (score 2):

This is [inclusion exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Let's examine a simplified version of the problem. Assume you had 2 sets `A`, `B`. Assume you are looking for the size of the subset that has exactly 1 element.

First, you calculate `|A| + |B|`. But in here, you counted the size of the intersection `| A [intersection] B|` twice, both in `|A|` and in `|B|`, so you reduce it and get `|A| + |B| - |A [intersection] B|`.

Similarly for 3 sets, you first add the sizes of all sets: `|A| + |B| + |C|`.

Then, you reduce all "connections" between two sets `|A [intersection] B|, |A [intersection] C|, |B [intersection] C|`. But now, you removed too much elements, you also removed the elements in `|A [intersection] B [intersection] C|`. To overcome it, you add this size.

So, generalizing it - you get for `n` sets, and `m` desired properties:

```
#of items with m properties: 
E(m) = sum { (-1)^(r-m) * Choose(r,m) * W(r) } 
Where: 
W(r) = summation of all intersections of size i, or formally:
W(r) = sum { W(p_k_1,...,p_k_r) | 1<=k_1<k_2<...<k_r<=n } 
W(pk1,...,pkr) = |X_k1 [intersection] X_k2 [intersection] .... [intersection] X_kr|
```

This explains how the `(-1)^x`  comes to play, we repeatidly include (add) and exclude (reduce) sizes. (-1)^x allows us to "automatically" reduce/add for every element in the summation.

---

As you said, `popcount(i xor req)` is counting the number of "up" bits in the representation of `i^req`. That means, `popcount()` is effectively your index `i` at the above formula, and your sets are: `X_i = all soldiers with required property i`.

This means if `k = popcount(i XOR req)`, `i` got exactly `k` "required" properties, and belongs in the above summation to the value when `r=k`, and thus the property add/substract depends on the value of `(-1)^k = (-1)^popcount(i XOR req)`

Comment: would you explain with a more clear example that's make a thing perfect to understand.

Comment: @amit thanks for the explanation !!! i little bit confuse about the term `2^f(i)−1`  i.e. no of ways for a particular set please explain that also

Comment: if X_i = all soldiers with required property i, which set do 0 belongs?